# Google Analytics Issue with Existing JS

Tags: jquery

On adding google analytics to my site - https://packetflow.co.uk, my AJAX search feature no longer works.
Ive tried playing the script in different postions and also header and foot. 
But all without luck.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-124434962-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-124434962-1');
</script>
```

Through Chromes dev console I see no errors. Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Comment: Shouldn't `dataLayer.push(arguments)` be `window.dataLayer.push(arguments)`

Comment: I checked the Google tracking code, and this is what they provide.

Comment: have you tried changing it to that?

Comment: Not yet, but the site has now started working. It seems like the issue appears then disappears

Comment: Ok goodluck my friend